# What are the bugs and their workarounds in Flash Player?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash

It seems a lot of questions for Flash/Flex are related to bugs in the Flash Player. What are some of the bugs and what are the workarounds. It would be nice to compile a list of known bugs and common workarounds.

Example:
In Flash Player 10 the DoubleClick event does not trigger in Firefox. The workaround is to avoid using the DoubleClick event in code.

Comment: A list of Flash Player related bugs can be found at Adobe's bug database at https://bugs.adobe.com/flashplayer/

Comment: Yes but having user experience with bugs in the wild along with their workarounds could be very beneficial for everyone developing on the platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SWFLoader memory leak](https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-18076) was instrumental in our choosing another platform for our app.  I'd love to learn the workaround/fix.

Comment: What platform did you choose?

Comment: It appears it has been fixed. The link you gave says it has been fixed and closed.

Answer (score 1):

[bugs.adobe.com](http://bugs.adobe.com) is the place for Flash Player and Flex bugs.